# How to parametrize decorator argument for test method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am in the situation that can be simplified to this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def items(request):
    # in reality, this is reading and parsing files
    return [c for c in request.node._obj._custom_attribute]


def decorated(param):
    def decorator(function):
        function._custom_attribute = param
        return function

    return decorator


class TestTesting:
    @decorated('value')
    def test_step(self, items):
        assert len(items) > 0
        # assert some other stuff
```

When writing tests, I am decorating test methods with a string value (in reality a file name) so that fixture can use that value to generate a list.

Is there a way to run test_step multiple times with different values of the decorator argument, similarly to how I would  parametrize test_step argument? I cannot change the decorator or the fixture.